# Can't traverse to vertices with unique properties in Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm looking for paths to get from one vertex to the other, avoiding vertices with properties already matched on that path.

Consider this example:

```
    Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();

    GraphTraversalSource t = graph.traversal();

    Vertex A = t.addV().property("age", 19).next();
    Vertex B = t.addV().property("age", 21).next();
    Vertex C = t.addV().property("age", 20).next();
    Vertex D = t.addV().property("age", 21).next();
    Vertex E = t.addV().property("age", 22).next();

    t.V(A).addE("knows").to(B).iterate();
    t.V(B).addE("knows").to(C).iterate();
    t.V(C).addE("knows").to(D).iterate();
    t.V(D).addE("knows").to(E).iterate();
    t.V(C).addE("knows").to(E).iterate();

    List<Path> paths = t.V(A)
            .repeat(
                    out()
            ).times(5).emit()
            .has("age", 22).path().toList();

    Assert.assertEquals(1, paths.size());
```

I'm looking for ways to go from A to E. There are two paths:

A->B->C->D->E
A->B->C->E

What I'm looking for is just the second one, because in the first path, B and D has the same age.

I tried to filter using as and by, but I failed to scale that to whole path. For instance, I can check the vertices not to match the first vertex' property, by doing the following:

```
    List<Path> paths = t.V(A).as("first")
            .repeat(
                    out()
                    .where(P.neq("first")).by("age")
            ).times(5).emit()
            .has("age", 22).path().toList();

    Assert.assertEquals(1, paths.size());
```

But as you can imagine, it doesn't filter the collisions in the middle of the path. I feel like there should be an easier way to do this that I'm missing. Is there a statement like as(), but instead of replacing the previous assignment, it keeps them in an array or something? How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare the current `age` against `all` previously seen `age`s. If there's any match, let the traverser die:

```
t.V(A).as("a").
  repeat(filter(loops().is(lt(5))).out().
         not(values("age").as("current").         /* current age   */
               select(all, "a").unfold().         /* previous ages */
               values("age").
                 where(eq("current"))).as("a")).  /* not() negates the match */
    until(has("age", 22)).
  path()
```